# ¿Es "hueco" una traducción correcta para "gap"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, sustantivos

Acabamos de tener en el trabajo la siguiente conversación:

> **Compañero**: No me han enviado los datos de los días 25 y 26 y ahora tengo un *gap* al final de la lista de datos.
>   **Yo**: Que no puedes decir "hueco", ¿no?
>   **Compañero**: Es que el hueco es lo que hay dentro del *gap*.

Y ahí ya me he quedado loco. Buscando en los diccionarios, encuentro:

> **[hueco, ca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Kknu99C)**
>
> Der. del lat. *occāre* 'ahuecar la tierra rastrillándola'.
>
> 8. m. Espacio vacío en el interior de algo.

Y por otro lado:

> **[gap](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gap)**
>
> - a separation in space
> - a break in continuity

Así que, efectivamente, parece que *gap* se refiere a esa discontinuidad que habría en la lista de datos, y *hueco* se refiere al espacio vacío que deja la discontinuidad. Siendo puntillosos, efectivamente en la lista no habrá ningún hueco, sino que en un momento dado el dato de la fecha pega un cambio inesperado (*gap* como discontinuidad). No hay exactamente un hueco, aunque lo habría si supusiéramos el espacio que deberían ocupar los datos que no están ahí.

¿Es, por tanto, un error traducir *gap* como *hueco*? ¿O sería recomendable usar otros sustantivos como *brecha*, *salto*, la mencionada *discontinuidad* u otros? ¿Existe algún caso en el que dicha traducción sea posible? A mí se me ocurre que el famoso "mind the gap" del metro de Londres se puede traducir como "ten cuidado con el hueco [entre el vagón y el andén]", pero ya pregunto por si acaso.

Comment: 9. m. Intervalo de tiempo o lugar.

Comment: Tiene varios significados. La interpretación se basa en el contexto no más. El problema radica también en el sobreuso de extranjerismos en vez de poner un poco más de esfuerzo y utilizar el vocabulario correcto en español.

Comment: The English word gap also has the sense of the thing which fills the gap. We have a gap year (taken between school and university). Geopgraphical gaps refer as much to what is in the gap (the Darien gap, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%B3n_del_Dari%C3%A9n) is an example. Note that the Spanish phrase for it definitely refers to the region in the gap. So I think your colleague is incorrect.

Comment: Creo que depende del contexto. Por ejemplo un "hueco en la vía" se refiere generalmente a un defecto en la via de forma "circular" y en inglés lo llamarían a "hole or a pot or a [pothole](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pothole) on the road" mientras que una grieta longitudinal que atraviese la via de lado a lado o un puente al que le falte una sección completa en inglés si sería un "gap on the road". Por lo tanto en este contexto una "gap" no es un "hueco" sino mejor una "grieta" o una "separación/división/abismo" entre otras. Gap casi siempre es algo 'longitudinal'

Comment: Para mí, *gap* = *hueco*, y no entiendo para nada la distinción que trató de hacer tu compañero, aunque si ambos viven en EEUU quizás sería más tolerante de tu parte no hacerle una corrección tan abierta....  Yo uso *hueco* para explicar cosas de fraseo musical a mi hijo, por ejemplo, "No dejes un hueco en cada barra" (es decir, entre compases) -- Let's not have a gap (in the sound) at each barline.  También en tu contexto me parece la palabra apta.

Comment: Tal y como lo planteas en la pregunta podría traducirse como "salto"

Answer (score 4):

Yo no veo problema con la palabra *hueco*, de hecho, es la palabra que utiliza la RAE en definiendo la palabra *laguna* (que, de hecho, es otra palabra que podrías usar en este contexto):

> **laguna**
>   **2.** *f.* En los manuscritos o impresos, omisión o hueco en que se dejó de poner algo o en que algo ha desaparecido por la acción del tiempo o por otra causa. || 
>   **3.** *f.* Defecto, vacío o solución de continuidad en un conjunto o una serie.

Una *brecha* para mí sería el punto donde empieza cualquier discontinuidad aunque técnicamente solo significa una ruptura, y un *salto* el espacio entre datos ordenados.  Pero *laguna*, *hueco* y *vacío* son algo más genéricos para mí.  Póngote un ejemplo de como lo ideo:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   4   6   8  10  12  14 
3   6   9  12  15  18  21
4   8  12  16  20  24  28
5  10  15  20  25  30  35
```

Aquí tenemos datos bien ordenados.  Voy ahora a quitar algunos datos.

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   4  --  --  10  12  14
3   6  --  --  15  18  21
4   8  --  --  20  24  28
5  10  15  20  25  --  35
```

Los seis datos borrados conjuntamente hacen una *laguna*, *hueco*, o *vacío*.  Pero siguiendo cualquier línea (digamos, 2, 4, 6 … horizontalmente) tenemos un salto del 4 al 10, otro del 6 al 15, etc.  Y yo diría que tenemos una brecha que aparece tras el 4, el 6, el 8, y antes del 10, 15, y 20 (y yendo verticalmente, después del 3 y 4 y antes del 15 y 20). Finalmente, hay otra *laguna/hueco/vacío* al final (después del 35) que podríamos considerar también una brecha, pero por carecer de otro número después, no lo veo muy oportuno llamarlo un salto (que implica dos lados).

Obviamente, si la serie es de 2D, no habría diferencia perceptible pues un hueco o una laguna constaría de un solo salto y brecha.  Y si es desordenado, salto y brecha ya no tendría tanto sentido, pero *laguna* o *hueco* o *vacío* sí.

---

<sup>(obviamente, *gap* en otros contextos tiene diversas traducciones como *brecha* cuando se trata de diferencias entre dos cosas, *lapsos* o *intervalos* o *desfases* al hablar de tiempo, *grietas* en piedra u otros materiales, *abismo* en sentido más poético o figurativo, etc; pero me limito al contexto que diste)</sup>

Comment: Quizás también *omisión*. (No tengo la menor idea cómo traducir *achievement gap*.)

Comment: @aparente001 **achivement gap** se puede traducir como la **brecha de realización académico-profesional**, o sea la diferencia en los logros y desarrollos de individuos segmentados de acuerdo a condicionantes tales como sus condiciones socio-económicas, raciales, etarias, etc.